# Check if the page is in the task's VMA

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

Is there a way in order to check if the page in question is used by specified process?
i.e. I have a pointer to `struct page` and `struct task_struct` and I want to obtain a boolean value denoting if the page is in process's VMA. Currently I'm stuck at getting the virtual address of the page in process's VMA. If I get it, I'll be able to traverse down the `pgd` and see if it is there.

I've tried the approach been taken in `vma_address()` (at `mm/rmap.c`) but while looping over task's `mm_struct->mmap` the virtual address appears to be different for each `vm_area_struct` in the list. This contradicts with the `find_vma()` (at 'mm/mmap.c`) which scans the task's VMA (though doing the search of corresponding rb-tree) working with the fixed address that is supplied as an argument.

So, what is the correct way of doing such things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that there's the only way to just scan the whole VMA jumping by `PAGE_SIZE` like so:

```
struct page *page_by_address(const struct mm_struct *const mm,
                             const unsigned long address)
{
    pgd_t *pgd;
    pud_t *pud;
    pmd_t *pmd;
    pte_t *pte;
    struct page *page = NULL;

    pgd = pgd_offset(mm, address);
    if (!pgd_present(*pgd))
        goto do_return;

    pud = pud_offset(pgd, address);
    if (!pud_present(*pud))
        goto do_return;

    pmd = pmd_offset(pud, address);
    if (!pmd_present(*pmd))
        goto do_return;

    pte = pte_offset_kernel(pmd, address);
    if (!pte_present(*pte))
        goto do_return;

    page = pte_page(*pte);
do_return:
    return page;
}

int contains_page(const struct mm_struct *const mm, struct page *const page)
{
    int contains = 0;

    if (mm != NULL) {
        const struct vm_area_struct *vma = mm->mmap;
        while (vma != NULL) {
            unsigned long address;
            for (address = vma->vm_start; !contains && address < vma->vm_end; address += PAGE_SIZE) {
                contains = (page_by_address(mm, address) == page);
            }

            vma = vma->vm_next;
        }
    }

    return contains;
}
```

Comment: How about huge and transparent huge pages? Your `page_by_address` implementation is bogus in that cases.

Comment: @IlyaMatveychikov If you are able to shed more light on the question, I encourage you to write you answer. My solution was implemented as a home task on "Operating Systems Design" course at the university. So it may suffer from mistakes. But that's the best I could did that time.

Comment: [follow_page](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.1/mm/memory.c#L1439) is a good example of how it would to be.

Comment: You can read about the transparent hugepages [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/359158/) and [there](http://lwn.net/Articles/423584/)

Comment: @IlyaMatveychikov probably kernel version is the key to misunderstanding: we were exploring version 2.6.32. Anyway, thanks for the info.

Comment: OK, but anyway don't forget for the huge pages. Use `pud_huge` and `pmd_huge` to check page table entries accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
for vma in task_struct:
    call page_address_in_vma(page, vma)
```

[Refer to this link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/rmap.c#L701).